# Regex for lat and long array

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to extract lat and long from a string that can be either in these 2 formats:

```
[-1.23,1.23]
(-1.23,1.23)
```

Right now this is what I am doing but only works with [] no ():

```
Location.new(coordinates: [string.gsub(/\[|,(.*)\]/,'').to_f, string.gsub(/\[(.*),\s|\]/,'').to_f])
```

I need the long, lat order because I am using mongodb.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post examples of different inputs and their respective outputs for the code you have now.

Comment: I'd consider just taking all but the first and last chars and splitting on the comma--seems easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex `/([\[\(])([^,]*),(.*?)([\]\)])/`.

I tested on node:

```
> var re = /([\[\(])([^,]*),(.*?)([\]\)])/;
> var s  = "[-1.23,1.23]";
> var t  = "(-1.23,1.23)";
> s.match(re)
[ '[-1.23,1.23]',
  '[',
  '-1.23',
  '1.23',
  ']',
  index: 0,
  input: '[-1.23,1.23]' ]
> t.match(re)
[ '(-1.23,1.23)',
  '(',
  '-1.23',
  '1.23',
  ')',
  index: 0,
  input: '(-1.23,1.23)' ]
```